Water based room spray
Hello I’m trying to mix essential oils to water and alcohol to create a room spray, unfortunately the oils rise to the surface and clog the atomiser pump.
Do you advise to use an emulsifier to the mix? And which one I should use?
Many thanks
P

The answer is in your question: "water base room sprays" are water based. Oils generally are not.

Essential oils don't mix well with water and will separate.  Here are two ways to fix your room spray:
Use a carrier oil:  Instead of water, try using a carrier oil, like jojoba oil or fractionated coconut oil. These oils will mix well with the essential oils and the alcohol.  You can find carrier oils at stores that sell essential oils.
Make an alcohol-based spray: If you want to use alcohol, you can make an alcohol-based room spray.  Just mix the essential oils with alcohol (like Everclear) and skip the water altogether.
Emulsifiers are not recommended for DIY room sprays. They can be tricky to use and may not work well with alcohol.
Here are some additional tips for making a room spray:
1.Always follow dilution recommendations for essential oils.
2.Test your spray in a small area before using it all over the room.
3.Label your spray with the ingredients and date.
